# Zookeeper-server package: where do I download for 3.5.1?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I follow the link on http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_requiredSoftware

to get Zookeeper Server package, and am taken to the one and only one tar file. From this I assumed that everything was on that tar file, but I get that the "Zookeeper data directory is missing..." when I set the dataDir correctly. Googling leads me to finding out that there is a zookeeper-server service and I may need to "init" it.  Where on earth do I get this zookeeper-server for version 3.5.1 alpha?